# How do I add values in a JS object?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, object

```js
let totals = 0;
// Object.values(json.consolidated.byLocation).forEach(
//  (val) => (totals += val.type.target)
// );

for (const val of Object.values(json.consolidated.byLocation)) {
    // console.log(val.type.target);
    totals += val.type.target;
}
console.log(totals);
```

This is my current code. When I `console.log(val.type.target)` within either of these loops, it outputs all the correct values, I just need to add them. I really don't like the whole "establish a variable, then loop through the values, repeatedly adding to the variable," so I'd like to avoid that if possible. Regardless, the totals are outputting NaN and I'm not sure why.
Thanks in advance.

```js
const json = {
  "consolidated": {
    "byLocation": {
      "first": {
        "type": {
          "target": 345,
          "othervalue": 12,
          "thirdvalue": 587
        },
        "extraneousvalue": 3021
      },
      "second": {
        "type": {
          "target": 425,
          "othervalue": 34,
          "thirdvalue": 302
        },
        "extraneousvalue": 4527
      },
      "third": {
        "type": {
          "target": 383,
          "othervalue": 54,
          "thirdvalue": 452
        },
        "extraneousvalue": 7348
      },
      "fourth": {
        "type": {
          "othervalue": 54,
          "thirdvalue": 452
        },
        "extraneousvalue": 7348
      }
    }
  }
}

let totals = 0;
// Object.values(json.consolidated.byLocation).forEach(
//  (val) => (totals += val.type.target)
// );

for (const val of Object.values(json.consolidated.byLocation)) {
  console.log(val.type.target);
  totals += val.type.target;
}
console.log(`total: ${totals}`);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `val.type.target` is a `number`?

Comment: Yes. When I console.log `val.type.target`, it outputs plain numbers without any string indicators, and typeof returns `number` as well.

Comment: What is `typeof(val.type.target)`?

Comment: You should add the object as (sample) input to your question so it can be debugged.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: @evolutionxbox typeof is `number`. 
@Andy I prefer to err on the side of caution when it comes to the sensitivity of the data I'm working with. It's just a JSON with a lot of nested objects haha. I'm trying to loop through the data and in each loop, navigate quite far into an object and grab the value in order to total all of the values up.

Comment: please add your `json.consolidated.byLocation` object (just that part, so call it const data or something), and turn this in a (mcve) runnable snippet.

Comment: If you can't post the exact object, post a similar example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you get NaN, then pinpoint the iteration when `total` *becomes* `NaN` (use debugger), and at that moment check the value of `val.type.target`. Let us know what that value is.

Comment: I added a runnable snippet -- but I'm confused because it's working here. All I did was switch up the values and the key names.

Comment: @trincot I found the issue. The very last object didn't have `target` so it was adding fine until it tried to add undefined LOL. Thanks guys.

Comment: So next time, when someone asks "Are you sure" (as in first comment), maybe distrust yourself, and look deeper. It is clear that the comment you replied with cannot be true, and it isn't. At least one (last one) had `typeof` **not** equal to "number".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to sum up numbers. Maybe something like reduce?
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-reduce/

```
Object.values(json.consolidated.byLocation).map(({ val: { type: { target } } }) => target).reduce((prev, current) => { prev  + current }, 0)
```